# How to regain credit after two car voluntary repossesion, five credit cards amount to 10K?

Tags: credit-score, financial-advisor

What are the necessary steps to get back on the road to fixing a credit after not paying 10K worth of credit cards (behind 6 payments for 6 months) and two car voluntary repossession?  This is after a job loss and personal set backs.  Any step by step, real answers would be great.

Comment: Should be fairly straight forward. Get a new job and repay all outstanding debt - the only way. The debt will not disappear. Contact the credit card company or your bank and hear which options they have - some times they are willing to cut a deal, since it is better for them to get some money rather than nothing. Perhaps you can cut your monthly payments into smaller pieces if that makes repayment easier on your finances.

Comment: So you misused credit previously, and you want to get back to the business of borrowing money.  Is your goal to have this happen again?  Perhaps make a change in your life and pay cash for things you can afford.

Comment: @PeteB.- I don't think we have enough information to assume the reason OP wants to increase their credit score is for more borrowing. Sometimes you need a good credit score just to rent an apartment.

Comment: Thanks for that point @PeteB. But thats not my goal.  Life comes at us in a different way we have no control under.